# How can I tell mathematica that $a, \space b, \space \omega$ are constants?

Tags: vector, vector-calculus

I want to differentiate the following vector:

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2\omega^2\sin^2(\omega t)+b^2\omega^2\cos^2(\omega t)}}\begin{pmatrix}-a \omega \sin(\omega t)\\b \omega \cos (\omega t)\end{pmatrix}$$

However if I type this into mathematica then mathematica doesn't recognize that $\omega$ and $a,b$ are constants. Any idea how I can tell mathematica that they are constants?

Comment: There are at least to direct hits within Mathematicas Help [Constants](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Constants.html) and [Local Constants](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LocalConstants.html) and [Constant](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Constant.html)

Comment: Look up [`Constant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Constant.html) in the Documentation Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I see why you need to? Simply differentiate only with respect to t, as follows:

[image]

then:
[image]

If you do ned to tell Mathematica they are constants then as Lou and m_goldberg have said use:

```
    SetAttributes[{a, b, ω}, Constant]
```

Comment: Thanks! I just realized I am an idiot for using the wolfram alpha input in mathematica and not the actual mathematica input. Thanks for your help!